# Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such module: VirtualElementary

Tags: r, sqlite

I have never used SQLite files before this morning but I wanted to explore available government geographical data that you can find here (in french): http://mffp.gouv.qc.ca/le-ministere/acces-aux-donnees-gratuites/

I would like to use the map with my datapoints to give each of my datapoints the information of the map relative to its position. To say it differently, I'd like to add the region info to my datapoints. 
But first I have an error message. This is the code that I'm using:

```
library(RSQLite)

#connect to my database : 
data <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="CLASSI_ECO_SQL/CLASSI_ECO_IEQM.sqlite")

#list all tables
tables <- dbListTables(data)

#exclude sqlite_sequence (contains table information)
tables <- tables[tables != "sqlite_sequence"]
lDataFrames <- vector("list", length=length(tables))

#create a data.frame for each table
for (i in seq(along=tables)) {
  lDataFrames[[i]] <- dbGetQuery(conn=data, statement=paste("SELECT * FROM '", tables[[i]], "'", sep=""))
}
```

And this is the error R is sending me back :

```
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  no such module: VirtualElementary
```

I have checked the help section of the library, and I'm trying to figure out what the issue is by myself but a little help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Single quoting of identifiers like tables and columns are invalid SQL. The query sent from R to SQLite is the following: `SELECT * FROM 'myTable'`. Try removing single quotes or change to brackets or backticks if table names have spaces or special characters.

Comment: Also, that error seems to derive from the [SpatialLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=VirtualElementary), an [open source extension of SQLite engine](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/home). Be sure you have correct versions. Maybe RSQLite does not support this type as possibly one of your tables is a *Virtual Table* using *VirtualElementary*.